# disable next 10 days in jQuery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    maxDate: "+30d",
    minDate:0
});
```

i want to disable the next 10 date from the current date, I am trying to do with this code but not working

Comment: Are past dates valid dates or not? with minDate and maxDate you can easily define a date range (minDate "+10d", maxDate: "+30d" may be an option). Do you need that or do you need something more complicated (e.g. all dates EXCEPT some range)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `minDate`:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    maxDate: "+30d",
    minDate: "+10d"
});
```

**RESULT**

[image]

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/yorch/egv4etx8/)

---

**NOTE:** this **will make selectable 20 days**, if you want to allow **30 days** selection starting 10 days from today you will need to set attribute `maxDate: "+40d"`:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    maxDate: "+40d",
    minDate: "+10d"
});
```

**ADD ON:**

> thank Jordi, if it possible to enable the current date only??

@achu you mean, enable today AND disable next 9 days?

> yes your right, today date should be enable.

This can be done via `jquery` or `javascript` simply removing the classes that does not allow you to select the day.

```
// select today's object, and remove classes ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled
$(".ui-datepicker-today").removeClass("ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled");
```

**DISCLAIMER:** Be careful, removing the classes should be done when datepicker is created, in this [**WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/egv4etx8/1/) is you can see I use onClick, look at [**THIS NON WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5rLr3eyv/), where same code non wrapped into a function, is executed in `onReady` when datepicker still does not exists.

**RESULT** (css also added ;)

[image]

---

Uhm.. that does not seem to be enough... Today's button cannot be clicked... I tried adding attributes and classes like other selectable days but no success and no more time today...

```
$( "#date" ).click(function() {
  $(".ui-datepicker-today").removeClass("ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled");
  $(".ui-datepicker-today").attr("data-handler", "selectDay");
  $(".ui-datepicker-today").attr("data-event", "click");
  $(".ui-datepicker-today").attr("data-month", "5");
  $(".ui-datepicker-today").attr("data-year" , "2016");
  $("a.ui-datepicker-today").attr("href" , "#");

  $(".ui-datepicker-today").removeClass("ui-datepicker-today");

});
```

Something still missing (hover not active...)

Comment: thank Jordi, if it possible to enable the current date only

Comment: @achu you mean, enable today AND disable next 9 days?

Comment: @achu sure, please kindly check my update, but be careful with disclaimer!! :)